# My raspberry pi is not working after I connected an android display to the one inside raspberry pi

Tags: pi-4, hdmi, display

So what happened was I connected an android display to my display thing inside the raspberry pi(not the hdmi). but then after that my raspberry pi did not work the pins all worked. But the hdmi did not work. Showed red light.

Comment: what's an `android display`?

Comment: You've probably killed your Pi by plugging in a non compatible device.

Comment: Can I fix it? All the pins work. its just that it is showing red light and the hdmi does not work after I plugged in a non compatible device @CoderMike

Comment: No, time to try and buy another one.

Comment: Have you tried it headless? It may not be totally broken, so at least useful for something in the future, just not anything that requires a display attached

Comment: @ShreyanshDash If the green light is blinking, that means it is doing something. Did you try reformatting the sd card with another os? If that doesn't work, try another sd card.

Comment: green light is not blinking